# Spin-front50 pod is crashing while deploying Spinnaker on Kubernetes with Minio as storage

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, minio

I am trying to deploy Spinnaker in Kubernetes with Minio as storage which is also running in Kubernetes. Now, spin-front50 pod does not start and is crashing. Looking at the pod logs, it is failing with

> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: spin-37f4958d-f5e4-4515-9894-25da8fcc7f66.minio-vocal-waterbuffalo.default

It seems that the code is adding the bucket name to the minio hostname and that is not being resolved in Kubernetes.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 storage can be accessed using the bucket name either as a domain or as a path. This can be controlled in halyard and set it up to access S3 as a path.

```
hal config storage s3 edit --path-style-access=true
```

Run this before deploying spinnaker using halyard. Then halyard will use `minio-vocal-waterbuffalo.default` as the host name.

This is also covered in Spinnaker issue [4431](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/4431)

For full disclosure, I work for [OpsMx](https://www.opsmx.com/) that provides commercial support for Spinnaker.